# selectmenu data-native-menu=“false” を用いると.on("change")や.changeが機能しない

Tags: monaca, jquery-mobile

monaca（Onsen-ui不使用）でjquery mobileを用いてセレクトメニューを作りました。
セレクトメニューで項目の選択を検出したかったので.on("change" や.changeを使用してみましたがこの関数が機能しません。
どうも原因はjqueryの見た目を実装するselectmenu data-native-menu=“false”部分にあるみたいで、これを削除するかtrueにして、ネイティブのセレクトメニューにするときちんと変更を検出してくれます。
ネイティブは見た目がダサいのでjqueryの見た目で変化を検出するよう実装したいのですが可能でしょうか？

[html]

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="selectbox">Basic:</label>
        <select name="selectbox" id="selectbox" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
            <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
            <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
            <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[javascript]

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page",function () {
  console.log(Date.now()); // will trigger one time only
  $("#selectbox").on("change", function () {
    console.log(Date.now()); // will trigger when you select a value
  });
});
```

引用元ソース：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351493/jqm-selectmenu-data-native-menu-false-running-twice

備考ですが、変化を検出したいのはセレクトメニューを2個作成し、この機能を用いて片方に連動したメニューを表示したいからです。
よろしくお願いします。